# I want to run OSX from my second hard drive on a Non-Mac

Tags: operating-systems

So I've heard of machines like Hackintoshes, but I don't want to build a whole separate system just to do a few things in OSX. Is it possible to just install OSX on my second hard drive and dual boot it with Windows?

Comment: That is the very definition of Hackintosh... installing OS X on a PC. It is against Apple's EULA & totally off-topic for SuperUser.

Comment: If you want to do just a few things, perhaps try a virtual machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't realize that. I'll do a VM. Thanks.

Comment: VM on non-Apple hardware is also against Apple EULA...

Comment: Questions about running OS X on non-Apple hardware ("Hackintosh") are off-topic because of the questionable legality of doing so. See [Are "Hackintosh" questions allowed?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471)

Answer (score 1):

**NO.  Not Legally.**

Apple OSX license Agreement:  http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX10103.pdf

Relevant Text:

> ...you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and
>   run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple-branded
>   computer...

And for the virtual world:

> ...to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances
>   of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on
>   each Mac Computer you own or control...